# Varnish update from version 3 to 5 - parameters expiry_sleep and queue_max

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

In our company we want update Varnish 3.0 to 5.2 version. Some of parameters in DAEMON_OPTS (/etc/init.d/varnish) has been renamed but I can't find what happened with parameters:
expiry_sleep and queue_max

Please, how can I replace these parameters? Thank  you very much! :)

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${ADDRESS} \
            -p connect_timeout=2\
            -p sess_timeout=10\
            -p syslog_cli_traffic=off\
            -p expiry_sleep=0.01\
            -p queue_max=300"
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

> DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${ADDRESS} \
>
> ```
>         -p connect_timeout=2\
>         -p sess_timeout=10\
>         -p syslog_cli_traffic=off\
>         -p timeout_linger=0.01\
>         -p thread_queue_limit=300"
> ```

Please consider reading the threading parameters as they have changed throughout the years.
varnishadm param.show -l | less